# Gerrit redirects to wrong URL

Tags: gerrit

I have installed Gerrit 2.12.3 on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 system.

- Gerrit is listening on `http://127.0.0.1:8102`.
- behind an nginx server, which is listening on `https://SERVER1:8102`.

Some contents of the `etc/gerrit.config` file is as follow:

```
[gerrit]
    basePatr = git
    canonicalWebUrl = https://SERVER1:8102/
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-https://127.0.0.1:8102/
```

And some contents of my nginx settings is as follow:

```
server {
    listen 10.10.20.202:8102 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server1.key;

    location / {
            # Allow for large file uploads
            client_max_body_size 0;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8102;
    }
}
```

Nearly all the function of Gerrit works very well now. But one problem I can not solved is that:

The url generated in notification email is `https://SERVER1:8102/11` which seems right, but when I click the link, it redirects to `https://SERVER1/#/c/11/` instead of `https://SERVER1:8102/#/c/11/`

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Mind the typo `basePatr`.

Answer (score 0):

That the port of [`gerrit.canonicalWebUrl`](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.3/config-gerrit.html#gerrit.canonicalWebUrl) and [`httpd.listenUrl`](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.3/config-gerrit.html#httpd.listenUrl) match makes no sense.

- Specify as `gerrit.canonicalWebUrl` the URL that is accessible to your users through the Nginx proxy, e.g., `https://gerrit.example.com`.
- This vhost in Nginx (listening to port 443) in turn is configured in the proxy to connect to the backend as specified in `httpd.listenUrl`, so e.g. port 8102 to which Gerrit would be listening in your case.

The `canonicalWebUrl` is just used that Gerrit knows its own host name, e.g., for sending email notifications IIRC.

You might also just follow [Gerrit Documentation](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.3/config-reverseproxy.html) and stick to the ports as described there.

EDIT: I really noticed that you want the proxy *AND* Gerrit both to listen on port 8102 - on a public interface respectively on 127.0.0.1. While this would work, if you really make sure that Nginx is *not* binding to 0.0.0.0, I think it makes totally no sense. Don't you want your users to connect via HTTPS on port 443?

Comment: Thanks for your information. The problem which I encountered is that:

a) The port 8102 works OK. b) The url generated in email is right.  c) But the url redirects to another wrong url.